# can WOL be used to boot a server up from an external network

Tags: boot, networking, server

so I recently set up an ubuntu server but have another one off-site about 40km from me on a network. I won't be at that location very often, my only way to turn the pc back on if the power may be tripped is WOL but as far as I'm concerned you can't turn it on if you are not in the network, is there a way to boot a pc from a different location and how?

Comment: no, WOL only works from within the local network, it doesn't traverse external-to-internal NAT.

Comment: If you can physically access to the server, you may be able to enable automatic power on when power is restored via the Advanced Power Management options in the BIOS. Alternatively, as @ThomasWard stated, you cannot use WOL unless you have access to the local network. If you can configure the network's router, you may be able to forward the magic packet but then so can everyone else. If you can `ssh` into any device on that network, be that the router or another machine, then you can issue the WOL packet from there.

Comment: Which router connects that location to the internet? Depending on the system of your router you might be able to issue a WOL packet from outside the network. See the answers to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/228891/wake-on-lan-over-internet-is-all-but-impossible